# Java: How can I view the XML that is sent and received by ServiceClient.sendReceive?

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am trying to debug an issue I am having with accessing a SOAP API using a .wsdl file using axis2. I am using this method:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#sendReceive(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement)

sendReceive is throwing an exception and I cannot even tell if it because of what is being sent or because of the server's response. I would like to be able to see the XML that is sent and received, but my attempts of finding it via packet sniffing were foiled by SSL. Specifically the errors I am getting are:

```
SOAPProcessingException First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but 
  found definitions  org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode 
  (StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:299)
```

and

```
XMLStreamException Can not output XML declaration, after other output has 
already been done.  com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError (BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
```

The first error makes me think that I should wrap the request with a SOAPEnvelope. When I do so is when I get the second error. I want to be able to view the XML so I can actually exactly what is happening with the messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and monitor the traffic on the adapter to determine what is being sent and received.  On Linux, read the man page for `tcpdump(8)`

Comment: I have used tcpdump to get a dump of the communication that happens but it is encrypted so I cannot actually see any of it.